# No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://... only on the first try

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, vaadin14

I am getting this exception, but only on the first time of running this program. When I reload the page, everything works just as intended. How do I fix my code to avoid the error on page load? I have recently started learning Java and this is one of my practice projects.

When manually loading the driver, another error says:

```
Loading class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. This is deprecated. The new driver class is com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
```

Here is the connection which returns the connection to the service:

```
package com.gmail.stefan.backend.dbservices;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class TestDBConnection {

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException   {

        System.out.println("Connecting...");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://42.5.63.191:2204/tod?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "admin", "admin");
        System.out.println("Connection succsessful!");      

        System.out.println("Connection still open. ");

        return con;
    }
}
```

Service:

```
package com.gmail.stefan.ui.views.login;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.gmail.stefan.backend.Author;
import com.gmail.stefan.backend.Message;
import com.gmail.stefan.backend.dbservices.TestDBConnection;
import com.gmail.stefan.ui.views.login.LogoutTest;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.DataProvider;

public class Service extends TestDBConnection{                                                              

    public static List<Author> selectAllAuthors() throws SQLException {

        try {

            Connection con = TestDBConnection.getConnection();
            String query = "select * from author";

            Statement st = null;

            st = con.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

            List<Author> list = new ArrayList<>();

            while (rs.next()) {
                String name = "";
                name = rs.getString("firstname");
                Author x = new Author(null, name, null);

                System.out.println(name);
                list.add(x);

            }

            st.close();
            con.close();
            System.out.println("First connection closed!");

            return list;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        // cannot return null
        return new ArrayList<Author>();

    }

    public static List<Author> selectFromAuthors() throws SQLException {
        try {
            Connection con = TestDBConnection.getConnection();
            String authorQuery = "select * from author"; 
            Statement ast = null;
            ast = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet ars = ast.executeQuery(authorQuery);
            List<Author> aList = new ArrayList<>();
            while (ars.next()) {
                int id; 
                String name = "";
                Timestamp createdon = null;

                id = ars.getInt(1);
                long uId = (long) id;
                name = ars.getString(2);
                createdon = ars.getTimestamp(3);
                Date date = new Date(createdon.getTime());

                Author b = new Author (uId, name, date);
                System.out.println(uId+" "+name+" "+createdon);
                aList.add(b);
            }
            ast.close();
            con.close();
            System.out.println("Second connection closed");

            return aList;
            }
        catch (SQLException s) {
            s.printStackTrace();

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just a warning message. Either add the newest `mysql-connection-java.jar` to your library or just add this code in your connection: `Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")`

Comment: Is this a web application? If so, you shouldn't use `DriverManager`, but instead use a `javax.sql.DataSource` backed by a connection pool. In any case, without a full stacktrace of the exception, we can't really help you. The error would indicate that the driver wasn't loaded.

Comment: Thank you for replying so fast. MySQL Connector version is 5.1.48 because the DB server is on v5 and installing a newer version will not work (I have tried). Also manually loading the driver with code has the first error which I have posted on top. Strange thing is that on second page load, driver is ok, and everything works like it should.  Yes Mark, this is a web application. Thank you, I will try.

Comment: If you get the warning _"Loading class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. This is deprecated. The new driver class is com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary."_, then you are using the MySQL Connector/J version 8 which supports MySQL 5.6 and higher.